# Change unity aspect ratio in fullscreen WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to change the aspect ratio when the game is fullscreen in WebGL? If so, does it pillarbox or stretch to compensate for the difference?

```
Screen.SetResolution(800, 600, true);
```

does not work in WebGL.

Comment: try setting resolution from player settings

Comment: I want to make it dynamic, so not build in.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible in WebGL, because you export with a body and canvas size, not screen resolution.

You need to set your canvas size in your template css file:

`<canvas id="c" width="400" height="300"></canvas>`

You can call this function to resize your canvas size when you go to full screen o resize your window:

```
function resizeCanvas() {
canvas = document.getElementById("c");
gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
var width = canvas.clientWidth;
var height = canvas.clientHeight;
if (canvas.width != width ||canvas.height != height) 
{
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
}
}
```

Comment: This is indeed the way to set your resolution for a canvas, but the moment you go full screen, unity automatically fills all available monitor space, even if your canvas has different proportions.

Comment: I Reply to your question. ASpect ratio is not posible to change on WebGL you only can set your canvas size, and resize the drawingbuffer.